# Share Ethernet over Wifi hotspot such that users can also access lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, ethernet

Hi There is a PC X Connected to ethernet .
Let ethernet contain 2 users - X and Y.

X creates a wifi hotspot to which another computer z connects.(through wifi obv)

Now I want Z to be able to access Y, ssh and maybe other protocols.

Note : Windows Doesn't allow to bridge ethernet with virtual adapter.